# Programmatically enable sharding + choosing shard key on a collection using casbah with Mongo 2.4

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I am attempting to programmatically "enable sharding" and set the "shard key" using java/scala API particularly casbah

Our config

```
scala 2.10
casbah 2.6 - "org.mongodb" % "casbah_2.10" % "2.6.0",
MongoDB 2.4.4
```

Also what is the casbah driver version for mongo 2.4.4 (with scala 2.10)

Our use case is such that, collections + indexes are created programmatically using the casbah scala API `dbConnection.getCollection(....)` and    `collection.ensureIndex(DBObject("orgId" -> 1), DBObject("background" -> true, "name" -> "org_idx", "unique" -> false))`

Is there an equivalent casbah API to programmatically, enableSharding and choose shardKey as well as we are currently sharding our mongo cluster to scale out.
Our database + collection names are not known ahead time and a dynamically created using API, so a enabling sharding using mongo shell is simply not an option.

Is there a better way to do this ? ANy recommendations?

Comment: since you are creating databases dynamically they will be round robin'ed around the shards - why do you need to shard any collections? wouldn't balancing load by putting different DBs on different shards be sufficient?

Comment: How will a database be sharded without an enableShard command or choosing a shard key on the collection ?

There are certain admin commands that have to be issued to do that

Comment: when you have  sharded cluster and you add a new database it will automatically be placed on a new(er) shard. databases will not be partitioned but they will all keep being placed on a next shard.  The only time you need enableShard and shardCollection is when you want to partition a collection - I don't see why you would need to partition all these collections that you are generating programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Asya .. I will get it a shot ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me, building on @Ross's answer, which didn't quite work for me:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

// Connect to MongoDB
val conn = MongoClient()
val adminDB = conn("admin")

// Enable sharding on the DB
adminDB.command(MongoDBObject("enableSharding" -> <database>))

// Create the index for our shard key
val shardKey = MongoDBObject("_id" -> "hashed")
conn(<database>)(<collection>).ensureIndex(shardKey)

// Enable sharding on the collection
adminDB.command(MongoDBObject("shardCollection" -> "<database>.<collection>", 
    "key" -> shardkey))
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and to help others - `enableSharding` is a command (see the [enableSharding docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shardCollection)) and you can run any command from casbah by using `db.command`.

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

// Connect to MongoDB
val conn = MongoClient()
val adminDB = conn("admin")


// Enable sharding
adminDB.command(MongoDBObject("shardCollection" -> "<database>.<collection>", "key" -> <shardkey>))
```

The  part should be a MongoDBObject defining the shardkey.

As Asya mentions this might not be the right solution for your use case but its certainly possible to do pragmatically using casbah.